# RegEx to get the alphabets or alphabets including the last digit with space

Tags: regex, alphanumeric

I have following strings:

```
Hyderabad RTC K1 1991-1998
Hyderabad RTC KK 1876-1897
Al Test K5 1876-9876
```

So, I want to get only the first part other than numbers from the above strings like:

```
Hyderabad RTC K1
Hyderabad RTC KK
Al Test K5
```

I have tried this `^[a-z]*([0-9] )?$` RegEx thinking that there will be any no of characters followed by a number and space or not.

Comment: Bear in mind that `[a-z]*` only matches lower case characters

Comment: Try [`^[A-Za-z]+(?:\s+[A-Za-z]+\d*)*`](https://regex101.com/r/MRbuVd/1). Could you please define the rules for matching these strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a capturing group to match any number of words ending with LetterNumber or both Letter followed by the digits-digits part:

```
^([A-Za-z]+\d*(?: [A-Za-z]+\d*)+) \d+-\d+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/js7orP/1)

Without the necessity to match the digits separated by a hyphen at the end, you can omit the capture group and the last part:

```
^[A-Za-z]+\d*(?: [A-Za-z]+\d*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ta7JHg/1)

Comment: @7koFnMiP You can check how the content was before the edit. It is a formatting issue. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63737298/edit/13d1ba57-4a37-4fec-b6a1-acb09f456831

Comment: Thanks but I can have any no of words ending with LetterNumber or both Letter then series of digits

Comment: @NAGASREE If you want to match any number of words ending with LetterNumber or both Letter followed by the digits-digits: `^((?:[A-Za-z]+\d* )+)\d+-\d+$` https://regex101.com/r/EIGH14/1 Without the necessity to match the digits separated at the end: `^[A-Za-z]+\d*(?: [A-Za-z]+\d*)*` https://regex101.com/r/ta7JHg/1

Comment: Regex cityAndCode = new Regex(@"^[A- Za - z] +\d * (?: [A - Za - z] +\d *)*");  It is throwing exception in [x-y] reverse order

Comment: @NAGASREE There should not be spaces `Regex cityAndCode = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+\d*(?:[A-Za-z]+\d)");` With one of the other patterns it would be `Regex cityAndCode = new Regex(@"^[A-Za-z]+\d*(?: [A-Za-z]+\d*)*");`